# Can I link a sentence ending in です with a ます sentence?

Tags: grammar

I want to translate 'I am a third year junior high school student and I am studying maths.
Is this correct:

私は中学三年生で、すうがくを勉強します。

Please give me a correction if this is incorrect.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can join two or more sentences using the te-form regardless of whether they end with ます or です.

Your attempt is grammatically perfectly correct, but is semantically a little weird because すうがくを勉強します would sound like "I (*will*) study math". To say "I *am studying* math," you have to use the [progressive form](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/present-progressive-tense-resultant-states-with-te-form/).

> 私は中学三年生で、数学【すうがく】を勉強しています。